# How to install Ubuntu from NFS Server

Tags: ubuntu, installation, nfs

How do I install Ubuntu where the files are on NFS server?

Comment: Can you add some additional information to your question?  Are you looking for help setting up an NFS server to do Ubuntu installs?  Or do you already have an NFS server setup or available with Ubuntu installation files there?  Do you just need assistance with the actual installation process?

Comment: I already have a PXE server and I use preseeding to install.I want to know how to tell the installer that the packages are located on NFS server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at and read through the documentation that Ubuntu provides?  They do a pretty good job, and they have lots of installation documentation available.  I'd start with the [Community Documentation Installation Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).  Everything you need is probably right there.

Comment: Look there but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OnNFSDriveWithLocalBoot

I suppose this is what you were looking for.

good luck!!